# A runtime error when assigning value to an unsigned integer

Tags: c++, crash, runtime, integer

I've just come across a very peculiar problem. When I try to assign a value to a particular unsigned int variable (no problem with other unsigned int variables), either with memcpy or the = operator, the program crashes with a runtime error. It does not always happen with one program running, but it always does when I run a second instance. I thoroughly checked the code by commenting different things out, so I'm pretty certain that the value assignment is the problem.

Many thanks in advance.

```
DWORD WINAPI RecvFunc(void* lpParameter)
{
  BYTE header[5];
  short size, datasize; // must be unsigned, changed to signed for testing
  int num;
  BYTE* data;
  BYTE opcode;

  while(true)
  {
    size = 0;

    while(size < 5)
    {
      num = recv(sock, (char*)(header + size), 5 - size, 0);

      if(num <= 0)
      {
        size = 0;
        break;
      }

      //MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Header piece ok", "", MB_OK);
      size += num;
    }

    if(size == 0)
    {
      //MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Header error", "", MB_OK);
      continue;
    }

    opcode = header[0];
    memcpy(&datasize, header + 1, sizeof(datasize));

    if(datasize > 5)
    {
      data = new BYTE[datasize - 5];
    }else{
      data = NULL;
    }

    while(size < datasize)
    {
      num = recv(sock, (char*)(data + size - 5), datasize - size, 0);

      //MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Packet post-recv", "", MB_OK);

      if(num <= 0)
      {
        size = 0;
        break;
      }

      size += num;
    }

    if(size == 0)
    {
      //MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Packet error", "", MB_OK);
      delete[] data;
      continue;
    }

    size -= 5;

    //MessageBox(g_hwnd, "Received a command", "New cmd", MB_OK);

    switch(opcode)
    {
       ...
    }

    if(data != NULL)
    {
      delete[] data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We need code to look at or all we can do is guess.

Comment: most likely a busted carburetor

Comment: I added the code to my original post. It's a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to an unsigned int variable is not the real cause of your problem, I can assure you :) Most likely, you have a buffer overflow somewhere else in your program.